# Font Face issues in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I created a test page for IE 8 to see if i could use Google fonts. You can find the code at the end of the question.

I am including every Google font i need by using a  element with a list of them.

Now, depending on the HREF attribute length in the  element, Google fonts might not work in IE 8.

Here are the cases:

If i have:

```
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css"
    href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine|Open+Sans|Droid+Sans|PT+Sans|Josefin+Slab|Arvo|Lato" />
```

**Google fonts DO NOT work in IE 8.**

**Now, if i remove "Lato", the last font specified:**

```
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css"
    href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine|Open+Sans|Droid+Sans|PT+Sans|Josefin+Slab|Arvo" />
```

**Google fonts DO WORK in IE 8.**

They work good in Chrome in both cases, this is an IE 8 related only.

HTML code for the test page:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css"
  href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine|Open+Sans|Droid+Sans|PT+Sans|Josefin+Slab|Arvo|Lato" />

<style>
div {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'Tangerine'; /* here is the google font */
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div>This div will get the google font family</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you file that issue at Google's issue tracker? That seems like a far more reliable way to get the best possible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's an issue with IE - for IE8 and below - one solution is to separate out the links for each font in a conditional statement - it doesn't like long font stack trace in the link attribute.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" />
<![endif]-->
```